# Clone Element without Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-clone

Is there a way to copy an element without copying it's children?

My goal is to duplicate a table, along with all classes, inline styles, etc. But I do not want to copy any of the table element's children.

I realize I could copy the entire table and then remove the children from the copy. But I want to minimize screen flicker and I seem to recall there are problems manipulating elements before they are visible in the DOM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cloning the entire table, emptying it and *then* adding it to the DOM should not cause any flicker. Can you reproduce the flicker issue?

Comment: you can clone the element, remove its children then add it to the dom... but if you clone, add to dom then remove the children might cause some problem(atleast might result in performance wise)

Comment: @techfoobar: It can be a very large table. It would at least cause a delay I'm sure. I'm willing to experiment with the flicker, but recall  running into problems trying to manipulate elements that were not yet visible. Would you make the cloned table visible while deleting the unneeded children?

Comment: @JonathanWood: You can manipulate a "disconnected" node the same as if it was part of the document. There is only a difference if you are trying to get information that makes only sense when the element is part of the document, like it's position in screen coordinates. Most DOM manipulation methods work the same regardless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you considered using native [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)? The argument controls whether children should be cloned as well.

```
var clone = table.cloneNode(false);
```

This does not clone event handlers though. <del>I'm not sure about styles set via the DOM API (probably not).</del>

Comment: if you mean `element.style.fontSize=...` it will get added to the style attribute so it gets cloned

Comment: [Indeed it does](http://jsfiddle.net/26kkh/). I wasn't sure because the MDN documentation mentions that event handlers are not cloned either.

Comment: Regarding listeners, those added inline (i.e. as HTML attributes) are cloned, as are those added using IE's *attachEvent*. But those added using *addEventListener* or directly as a property are not (per the W3C [*Interface EventListener*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-EventListener))

Answer (score 1):

use [.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)

```
var t = document.createElement("table");
t.setAttribute("style",'background:#0F0; font-size:12px;');
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
tr.appendChild(td);
t.appendChild(tr);
var clone = t.cloneNode();
console.log(clone);
//outputs 
//<table style="background:#0F0; font-size:12px;"></table>
```

Comment: Note that in older versions of IE, TR elements must be appended to a TBODY element, not to a TABLE element. An alternative is to create the TR using [*table.insertRow*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-table-insertrow), which appends a row to the table's TBODY, or creates one if there isn't one already available.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way to do it, probably the ugliest one so far posted, but I'm just adding to the possibilities. If it were me, I would use the one by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469693/519383).

It basically gets the `outerHTML` and `innerHTML` substracting one to the other: `table.prop('outerHTML').replace(table.prop('innerHTML'), '');`. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yawnz/).

**HTML**

```
<table class="some-class" style="border:1px solid #000" id="t">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#t').addClass('another-class');
    var table = $('#t')
    var html = table.prop('outerHTML').replace(table.prop('innerHTML'), '');
    $('body').append($(html).append('<tr><td>second</td></tr>'));
});
```

**CSS**

```
.some-class {
    color: #00F
}
.another-class {
    color: #00F;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```